# How can I Display a Component When I Search in Input React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve the function that when I search for the name like Jupiter, Earth, Saturn, I want to show the components in the following order:

1. Jupiter
2. Earth
3. Saturn

I created components like this:

`Earth.js`:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 h-32 border border-gray-200 my-4">
  <div className="relative">
    <img
      className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-32 object-cover"
      src="img/earth.jpeg"
    />
  </div>
  <p className="text-3xl font-bold text-left p-10">Earth</p>
</div>;
```

Here is some components that are similar to the Earth component.

And here is my `App.js` input function:

```
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };

          <div className="md:w-2/3">
            <input
              className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500"
              id="inline-full-name"
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete, but I think this is what you want:

**App.js**

```
import Earth from './components/Earth';
import Jupiter from './components/Jupiter';
import Saturn from './components/Saturn';

const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
};

const loadPlanet = (
    if (searchQuery === "Jupiter") {
      return <Jupiter></Jupiter>
    } else if (searchQuery === "Earth") {
      return <Earth></Earth>
    } else if (searchQuery === "Saturn") {
      return <Saturn></Saturn>
    } else {
      return "";
    }
)

return (
  <div className="md:w-2/3">
    <input
      className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500"
      id="inline-full-name"
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
    />
  </div>

  {loadPlanet}
  
)
```